# SQL Server search for a column by name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm doing some recon work and having to dig through a few hundred SQL Server database tables to find columns.

Is there a way to easily search for columns in the database and return just the table name that the column belongs to?

I found [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2035), but that also returns Stored procedures with that column name in it...

Comment: I created a [procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681429/4271117) to search procedures, tables, views, or jobs. You can specify to search only one of them or all of them. The link points to an answer at stack overflow

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) FROM sys.columns WHERE name = 'foo'
```

This includes views though but can be further filtered . It may be useful though.

More generally...

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'foo'
```

[sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

To get the

1) full column name
2) object name (including schema)
3) object type (table/view)
4) data type (nice format: varchar(6) or numeric(5,2), etc.)
5) null/not null
6) information on identity, check constraint, and default info

try this:

```
DECLARE @Search varchar(200)
SET @Search='YourColumnName'  --can be a partial or a complete name

SELECT
    s.name as ColumnName
        ,sh.name+'.'+o.name AS ObjectName
        ,o.type_desc AS ObjectType
        ,CASE
             WHEN t.name IN ('char','varchar') THEN t.name+'('+CASE WHEN s.max_length<0 then 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),s.max_length) END+')'
             WHEN t.name IN ('nvarchar','nchar') THEN t.name+'('+CASE WHEN s.max_length<0 then 'MAX' ELSE CONVERT(varchar(10),s.max_length/2) END+')'
            WHEN t.name IN ('numeric') THEN t.name+'('+CONVERT(varchar(10),s.precision)+','+CONVERT(varchar(10),s.scale)+')'
             ELSE t.name
         END AS DataType

        ,CASE
             WHEN s.is_nullable=1 THEN 'NULL'
            ELSE 'NOT NULL'
        END AS Nullable
        ,CASE
             WHEN ic.column_id IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE ' identity('+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),ic.seed_value),'')+','+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),ic.increment_value),'')+')='+ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(10),ic.last_value),'null')
         END
        +CASE
             WHEN sc.column_id IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE ' computed('+ISNULL(sc.definition,'')+')'
         END
        +CASE
             WHEN cc.object_id IS NULL THEN ''
             ELSE ' check('+ISNULL(cc.definition,'')+')'
         END
            AS MiscInfo
    FROM sys.columns                           s
        INNER JOIN sys.types                   t ON s.system_type_id=t.system_type_id and t.is_user_defined=0
        INNER JOIN sys.objects                 o ON s.object_id=o.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas                sh on o.schema_id=sh.schema_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.identity_columns  ic ON s.object_id=ic.object_id AND s.column_id=ic.column_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.computed_columns  sc ON s.object_id=sc.object_id AND s.column_id=sc.column_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.check_constraints cc ON s.object_id=cc.parent_object_id AND s.column_id=cc.parent_column_id
    WHERE s.name LIKE '%'+@Search+'%'
```

Answer (score 6):

```
select c.name as ColumnName, o.name as TableName
from sys.columns c
inner join sys.objects o on c.object_id = o.object_id
where c.name = 'MyColumnName'
```

Answer (score 1):

http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=sqlsearch&gclid=COSfqe_mmKQCFSE1gwodSxOrEQ

This should do it for you. I use it everyday.

Answer (score 1):

This stored procedure will search for table.name and column.name pairs.

I use when I have "WhateverId" in code and I want to know where that is (probably) stored in the database without actually having to read through and understand the code. :)

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC FindColumns  
@ColumnName VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,  
@TableName VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL    
AS    
    
SELECT T.[name] AS TableName, C.[name] AS ColumnName  
FROM sys.all_columns C    
JOIN sys.tables T ON C.object_id = T.object_id    
JOIN sys.types CT ON C.user_type_id = CT.user_type_id    
WHERE (@ColumnName IS NULL OR C.[name] LIKE '%' + TRIM(@ColumnName) + '%')  
AND (@TableName IS NULL OR T.[name] LIKE '%' + TRIM(@TableName) + '%')  
ORDER BY T.[name], C.[name]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_name from information_schema.columns
where column_name = '<your column name here>'
```

Using the information_schema views is 'more correct' as system details in the system databases are subject to change between implementations of SQL Server.

Comment: Why would you have DISTINCT when column names must be unique in a table?

Comment: I was under the strange impression that the table name could show up multiple times (especially if you have multiple databases with similar schemas, and don't restrict your query to a specific schema or database). In hindsight the distinct is probably useless in most contexts.