# Search text in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to search a text from all my database stored procedures. I use the below SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%[ABD]%';
```

I want to search for `[ABD]` in all stored procedures including square brackets, but it's not giving the proper result. How can I change my query to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find a stored procedure containing <text>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079457/how-do-i-find-a-stored-procedure-containing-text)

Comment: Someday a whole week may go by when I don't search for and use this script. This week was not that week.

Answer (score 702, accepted):

Escape the square brackets:

```
...
WHERE m.definition Like '%\[ABD\]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Then the square brackets will be treated as a string literals not as wild cards.

Comment: doen't give schema name :(

Comment: @Imad You can get the schema name by adding `SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS Schema_Name` to the select clause.

Comment: This doesn't work with longer stored procedures.  Use Ullas's SQL below instead.

Comment: I found out the hard way that this answer will only search the first 4000 characters of stored procedure text.  Check out this link for the real answer.  http://sqlhints.com/2011/10/01/how-to-find-all-the-stored-procedures-having-a-given-text-in-it/

Comment: Same here, information_schema didn't search content-text (within SProcs), instead use of "sys.procedures" worked for me. I understand that Microsoft recommends the use of information_schema, however apparently this is not working for many, hence Microsoft should look into this issue.

Comment: SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), 
     OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)
    FROM sys.procedures
    WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) LIKE '%[ADB]%'

Comment: @patricus Do you know some way to get the DB name besides the schema name? Thanks

Comment: fun fact: _ is a wildcard too in LIKE expressions!

Comment: Tested with over 128k Characters and it worked.
@CharlesGraham I created a test/temporary stored procedure with over 128k characters, and searched for something at the end using this and it worked fine.

Answer (score 439):

Try this request:

**Query**

```
SELECT name
FROM   sys.procedures
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE '%strHell%'
```

Comment: I had to run as admin for this work for me.

Comment: Does this option have the 4000 character limit on it?

Comment: Protip you need to be using the database you are searching before you run this. Also YES this works for procedures longer than 4000 characters. I even created a stored procedure with well over a 4000 character count, with a query string at the end, and it turned up in the result. THIS ONE RIGHT HERE IS WHAT YOU NEED TO USE.

Answer (score 64):

I usually run the following to achieve that:

```
select distinct object_name(id) 
from syscomments 
where text like '%[ABD]%'
order by object_name(id)
```

Comment: this is good as it not only searches Stored Procs but also views and definitions of tables etc

Comment: this is the correct anwser

Comment: @Daniel Kelley
this is the exact answer, thanks

Answer (score 58):

Have you tried using some of the third party tools to do the search? There are several available out there that are free and that saved me a ton of time in the past.

Below are two SSMS Addins I used with good success.

[ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx) – Searches both schema and data in databases and has additional features such as dependency tracking and more…

[SSMS Tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) – Has same search functionality as previous one and several other cool features. Not free for SQL Server 2012 but still very affordable.

I know this answer is not 100% related to the questions (which was more specific) but hopefully others will find this useful.

Answer (score 45):

Good practice to work with SQL Server.

Create below stored procedure and set short key,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Searchinall]       
(@strFind AS VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL PROCEDURES        
    BEGIN
        SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) SP_Name
              ,OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) SP_Definition
        FROM   sys.procedures
        WHERE  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
    END 

    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL VIEWS        
    BEGIN
        SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) View_Name
              ,OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) View_Definition
        FROM   sys.views
        WHERE  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
    END 

    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL FUNCTION        
    BEGIN
        SELECT ROUTINE_NAME           Function_Name
              ,ROUTINE_DEFINITION     Function_definition
        FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
        WHERE  ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
               AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
        ORDER BY
               ROUTINE_NAME
    END

    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL TABLES OF DATABASE.    
    BEGIN
        SELECT t.name      AS Table_Name
              ,c.name      AS COLUMN_NAME
        FROM   sys.tables  AS t
               INNER JOIN sys.columns c
                    ON  t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
        WHERE  c.name LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
        ORDER BY
               Table_Name
    END
END
```

Now - Set short key as below,

[image]

So next time whenever you want to find a particular text in any of the four objects like `Store procedure`, `Views`, `Functions` and `Tables`. You just need to write that keyword and press shortcut key.

**For example:** I want to search 'PaymentTable' then write 'PaymentTable' and make sure you select or highlight the written keyword in query editor and press shortcut key `ctrl+4` - it will provide you full result.

Comment: In SSMS v18.2 (connected to Azure) the code works great. The short key returns `Procedure or function 'Searchinall' expects parameter '@strFind', which was not supplied` Any ideas?

Comment: @gordon613  have you typed keyword for searching while pressing short cut key on SSMS? e.g. 'Employee' and then ctrl + 4

Comment: @pedram.- thanks! I have now got it working - on my setup you need to type the keyword, then highlight it, and *then* press CTRL+4

Comment: yes we need to highlight/select the keyword before pressing CTRL+4. Thanks mate!

Comment: Works great. (Though I had to restart SSMS after creating the shortcut key for it to recognize it.) To set a shortcut (SSMS 18.2): Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard - Query Shortcuts

Comment: @AngelWarrior, You might have tried it in new query and it should have worked for you. I mean no need to restart the SSMS. Thanks for providing Shortcuts path for SSMS 18.2.

Comment: One that is always missing is search through **SQL job steps**. I have seen quite few cases when that search was not run and we kept looking for something that was updating our data outside of all objects your query covers.

Answer (score 21):

**Please take this as a "dirty" alternative** but this saved my behind many times especially when I was not familiar with the DB project. Sometimes you are trying to search for a string within all SPs and forget that some of the related logic may have been **hiding between Functions and Triggers** or it can be simply worded differently than you thought.

From your MSSMS you may right click your DB and select
**`Tasks -> Generate Scripts`** wizard to output all the SPs, Fns and Triggers into a single .sql file.

[image]

Make sure to select Triggers too!

[image]

**Then just use Sublime or Notepad** to search for the string you need to find. **I know this may be quite inefficient and paranoid approach but it works :)**

Answer (score 13):

You can also use this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%Search_String%'
```

Comment: -1 Downside compared to other options is `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES.ROUTINE_DEFINITION` only holds first 4000 characters of the routine.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT name , type_desc , create_date , modify_date
FROM   sys.procedures 
WHERE  Object_definition(object_id) LIKE '%High%'
```

Answer (score 8):

```
select top 10 * from
sys.procedures
where object_definition(object_id) like '%\[ABD\]%'
```

Answer (score 8):

It might help you!

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
      A.NAME AS OBJECT_NAME,
      A.TYPE_DESC
      FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES M 
      INNER JOIN SYS.OBJECTS A ON M.OBJECT_ID = A.OBJECT_ID
      WHERE M.DEFINITION LIKE '%['+@SEARCH_TEXT+']%'
      ORDER BY TYPE_DESC
```

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(id) 
    FROM syscomments 
    WHERE [text] LIKE '%flags.%' 
    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1 
    GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(id)
```

Thats include comments

Comment: You shouldn't use syscomments for this purpose. The text field cuts off at 4000 characters. The definition field from sys.sql_modules seems to store the entire text (more than 4000 anyway)

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   o.name AS Object_Name,
   o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m        INNER JOIN        sys.objects o 
     ON m.object_id = o.object_id WHERE m.definition Like '%[String]%';
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME([id]),[text] 

 FROM syscomments   

 WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [id] FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype IN 

 ('TF','FN','V','P') AND status >= 0) AND  

 ([text] LIKE '%text to be search%' )
```

OBJECT_NAME([id]) --> Object Name (View,Store Procedure,Scalar Function,Table function name)

id  (int) = Object identification number

xtype   char(2) Object type. Can be one of the following object types:

FN = Scalar function

P = Stored procedure

V = View

TF = Table function

Answer (score 5):

I created a procedure to search text in procedures/functions, tables, views, or jobs. The first parameter @search is the search criterion, @target the search target, i.e., procedures, tables, etc. If not specified, search all. @db is to specify the database to search, default to your current database. Here is my query in dynamic SQL.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_find_objects]
(
    @search VARCHAR(255),
    @target VARCHAR(255) = NULL,
    @db VARCHAR(35) = NULL
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @USEDB NVARCHAR(50)

IF @db <> '' SET @USEDB = 'USE ' + @db
ELSE SET @USEDB = ''

IF @target IS NULL SET @target = ''

SET @TSQL = @USEDB + '

DECLARE @search VARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @target VARCHAR(128)

SET @search = ''%' + @search + '%''
SET @target = ''' + @target + '''

IF @target LIKE ''%Procedure%'' BEGIN
    SELECT o.name As ''Stored Procedures''
    FROM SYSOBJECTS o 
    INNER JOIN SYSCOMMENTS c ON o.id = c.id
    WHERE c.text LIKE @search
        AND o.xtype IN (''P'',''FN'')
    GROUP BY o.name
    ORDER BY o.name
END

ELSE IF @target LIKE ''%View%'' BEGIN
    SELECT o.name As ''Views''
    FROM SYSOBJECTS o 
    INNER JOIN SYSCOMMENTS c ON o.id = c.id
    WHERE c.text LIKE @search
        AND o.xtype = ''V''
    GROUP BY o.name
    ORDER BY o.name
END

/* Table - search table name only, need to add column name */
ELSE IF @target LIKE ''%Table%'' BEGIN
    SELECT t.name AS ''TableName''
    FROM sys.columns c 
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE @search
    ORDER BY TableName
END

ELSE IF @target LIKE ''%Job%'' BEGIN
    SELECT  j.job_id,
        s.srvname,
        j.name,
        js.step_id,
        js.command,
        j.enabled 
    FROM    [msdb].dbo.sysjobs j
    JOIN    [msdb].dbo.sysjobsteps js
        ON  js.job_id = j.job_id 
    JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers s
        ON  s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
    WHERE   js.command LIKE @search
END

ELSE BEGIN 
    SELECT o.name As ''Stored Procedures''
    FROM SYSOBJECTS o 
    INNER JOIN SYSCOMMENTS c ON o.id = c.id
    WHERE c.text LIKE @search
        AND o.xtype IN (''P'',''FN'')
    GROUP BY o.name
    ORDER BY o.name

    SELECT o.name As ''Views''
    FROM SYSOBJECTS o 
    INNER JOIN SYSCOMMENTS c ON o.id = c.id
    WHERE c.text LIKE @search
        AND o.xtype = ''V''
    GROUP BY o.name
    ORDER BY o.name

    SELECT t.name AS ''Tables''
    FROM sys.columns c 
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE @search
    ORDER BY Tables

    SELECT  j.name AS ''Jobs''
    FROM    [msdb].dbo.sysjobs j
    JOIN    [msdb].dbo.sysjobsteps js
        ON  js.job_id = j.job_id 
    JOIN    master.dbo.sysservers s
        ON  s.srvid = j.originating_server_id
    WHERE   js.command LIKE @search
END
'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @TSQL
```

> **Update:**
>   If you renamed a procedure, it only updates `sysobjects` but not `syscomments`, which keeps the old name and therefore that procedure will not be included in the search result unless you drop and recreate the procedure.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://thesitedoctor.co.uk/blog/search-every-table-and-field-in-a-sql-server-database-updated/) to search column name.

Answer (score 5):

A different version, To make query more appropriate for different coding practices.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       O.NAME AS OBJECT_NAME,
       O.TYPE_DESC
  FROM SYS.SQL_MODULES M
       INNER JOIN
       SYS.OBJECTS O
         ON M.OBJECT_ID = O.OBJECT_ID
 WHERE UPPER(M.DEFINITION) LIKE UPPER('%Your Text%');
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects  o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE CHARINDEX('[ABD]',m.definition) >0 ;
```

Using [PATINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects  o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE PATINDEX('[[]ABD]',m.definition) >0 ;
```

Using this double `[[]ABD]` is similar to escaping :

```
WHERE m.definition LIKE '%[[]ABD]%'
```

Answer (score 4):

also try this :

```
   SELECT ROUTINE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
    WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%\[ABD\]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

This query is search text in stored procedure from all databases.

```
DECLARE @T_Find_Text VARCHAR(1000) = 'Foo'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T_DBNAME') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T_DBNAME
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T_PROCEDURE') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #T_PROCEDURE

CREATE TABLE #T_DBNAME
(
    IDX int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
    , DBName VARCHAR(255)
)

CREATE TABLE #T_PROCEDURE
(
    IDX int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
    , DBName VARCHAR(255)
    , Procedure_Name VARCHAR(MAX)
    , Procedure_Description VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #T_DBNAME (DBName)
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases

DECLARE @T_C_IDX INT = 0
DECLARE @T_C_DBName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @T_SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @T_SQL_PARAM NVARCHAR(MAX) 

SET @T_SQL_PARAM =   
    '   @T_C_DBName VARCHAR(255)
        , @T_Find_Text VARCHAR(255)
    '  


WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 IDX FROM #T_DBNAME WHERE IDX > @T_C_IDX ORDER BY IDX ASC)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 
    @T_C_DBName = DBName 
    FROM #T_DBNAME WHERE IDX > @T_C_IDX ORDER BY IDX ASC

    SET @T_SQL = ''

    SET @T_SQL = @T_SQL + 'INSERT INTO #T_PROCEDURE(DBName, Procedure_Name, Procedure_Description)'
    SET @T_SQL = @T_SQL + 'SELECT SPECIFIC_CATALOG, ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION '
    SET @T_SQL = @T_SQL + 'FROM ' + @T_C_DBName +  '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES  '
    SET @T_SQL = @T_SQL + 'WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE ''%''+ @T_Find_Text + ''%'' '
    SET @T_SQL = @T_SQL + 'AND ROUTINE_TYPE = ''PROCEDURE'' '

    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @T_SQL, @T_SQL_PARAM, @T_C_DBName, @T_Find_Text
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT @T_C_DBName + ' ERROR'
    END CATCH

    SET @T_C_IDX = @T_C_IDX + 1
END

SELECT IDX, DBName, Procedure_Name FROM #T_PROCEDURE ORDER BY DBName ASC
```

Comment: Works great -- thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

This search routine is based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33631029/2735286 and contains the schema name too in the search results:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Searchinall] (@strFind AS VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL PROCEDURES        
    BEGIN
        SELECT s.name SP_Schema_Name, OBJECT_NAME(p.OBJECT_ID) SP_Name
              ,OBJECT_DEFINITION(p.OBJECT_ID) SP_Definition
            FROM   sys.procedures p
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on p.schema_id = s.schema_id
            WHERE  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
    END 

    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL VIEWS        
    BEGIN
        SELECT s.name SP_Schema_Name, OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) View_Name
                ,OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) View_Definition
            FROM   sys.views v
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on v.schema_id = s.schema_id
            WHERE  OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
    END 

    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL FUNCTION        
    BEGIN
        SELECT ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME           Function_Name
              ,ROUTINE_DEFINITION     Function_definition
        FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
        WHERE  ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
               AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'FUNCTION'
        ORDER BY
               ROUTINE_NAME
    END

    --TO FIND STRING IN ALL TABLES OF DATABASE.    
    BEGIN

        SELECT s.name SP_Schema_Name, t.name      AS Table_Name
                ,c.name      AS COLUMN_NAME
        FROM   sys.tables  AS t
                INNER JOIN sys.columns c
                    ON  t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        WHERE  c.name LIKE '%'+@strFind+'%'
        ORDER BY
                Table_Name
    END
END
```

Here is how you use it:

```sql
execute [dbo].[Searchinall] 'cust'
```

Here is an alternative which lists all objects with a specific keyword in one single query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       s.name AS Schema_Name, 
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_modules m
       INNER JOIN
       sys.objects o
         ON m.object_id = o.object_id
       INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%dim_forex%' ESCAPE '\' order by 3;
```

This query should return the same results and the procedure call in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select distinct OBJECT_NAME(id) from syscomments where text like '%string%' AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
    SEARCH SPROCS & VIEWS

    The following query will allow search within the definitions 
    of stored procedures and views.

    It spits out the results as XML, with the full definitions, 
    so you can browse them without having to script them individually.

*/

/*
   STEP 1: POPULATE SEARCH KEYS. (Set to NULL to ignore)
*/
DECLARE 
    @def_key varchar(128) = '%foo%',      /* <<< definition search key */
    @name_key varchar(128) = '%bar%',     /* <<< name search key       */
    @schema_key varchar(128) = 'dbo';     /* <<< schema search key     */

;WITH SearchResults AS (
    /* 
       STEP 2: DEFINE SEARCH QUERY AS CTE (Common Table Expression)
    */
    SELECT 
        [Object].object_id                       AS [object_id],    
        [Schema].name                            AS [schema_name], 
        [Object].name                            AS [object_name],
        [Object].type                            AS [object_type],
        [Object].type_desc                       AS [object_type_desc],
        [Details].definition                     AS [module_definition]
    FROM  
        /* sys.sql_modules = where the body of sprocs and views live */
        sys.sql_modules AS [Details] WITH (NOLOCK)
    JOIN
        /* sys.objects = where the metadata for every object in the database lives */
        sys.objects AS [Object] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Details].object_id = [Object].object_id
    JOIN 
        /* sys.schemas = where the schemas in the datatabase live */
        sys.schemas AS [Schema] WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Object].schema_id = [Schema].schema_id
    WHERE 
        (@def_key IS NULL OR [Details].definition LIKE @def_key)      /* <<< searches definition */
        AND (@name_key IS NULL OR [Object].name LIKE @name_key)       /* <<< searches name       */
        AND (@schema_key IS NULL OR [Schema].name LIKE @schema_key)   /* <<< searches schema     */
)
/* 
   STEP 3: SELECT FROM CTE INTO XML
*/

/* 
    This outer select wraps the inner queries in to the <sql_object> root element 
*/
SELECT 
(
    /* 
        This inner query maps stored procedure rows to <procedure> elements
    */
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
        [object_id]                            AS [@object_id], 
        [schema_name] + '.' + [object_name]    AS [@full_name],
        [module_definition]                    AS [module_definition]
    FROM
        SearchResults
    WHERE
        object_type = 'P'
    ORDER BY
        [schema_name], [object_name]
    FOR XML
        PATH ('procedure'), TYPE
) AS [procedures],  /* <<< as part of the outer query, 
                           this alias causes the <procedure> elements
                           to be wrapped within the <procedures> element */
(
    /* 
        This inner query maps view rows to <view> elements
    */
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
        [object_id]                            AS [@object_id], 
        [schema_name] + '.' + [object_name]    AS [@full_name],
        [module_definition]                    AS [module_definition]
    FROM
        SearchResults
    WHERE
        object_type = 'V'
    ORDER BY
        [schema_name], [object_name]
    FOR XML
        PATH ('view'), TYPE
) AS [views]  /* <<< as part of the outer query, 
                     this alias causes the <view> elements
                     to be wrapped within the <views> element */
FOR XML 
    PATH ('sql_objects')
```

Answer (score 0):

Every so often I use this script to figure out which procs to modify, or to figure out what uses a column of a table, or that table at all to remove some old junk.  It checks each database on the instance it is ran on by the wonderfully supplied sp_msforeachdb.

```
if object_id('tempdb..##nothing') is not null
    drop table ##nothing

CREATE TABLE ##nothing
(
    DatabaseName varchar(30),
    SchemaName varchar(30),
    ObjectName varchar(100),
    ObjectType varchar(50)
)

EXEC master.sys.sp_msforeachdb 
'USE ?
insert into ##nothing
SELECT 
db_name() AS [Database],
[Scehma]=schema_name(o.schema_id), 
o.Name, 
o.type 
FROM sys.sql_modules m
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
    ON o.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE 
    m.definition like ''%SOME_TEXT%'''  
--edit this text

SELECT * FROM ##nothing n
order by OBJECTname
```

Comment: oh, ya... is that so!

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Applicable for SQL 2005+
USE YOUR_DATABASE_NAME //;
    GO

SELECT [Scehma] = schema_name(o.schema_id)
    ,o.NAME
    ,o.type
FROM sys.sql_modules m
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE m.DEFINITION LIKE '%YOUR SEARCH KEYWORDS%'
GO
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also use

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Search](
    @Filter nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT name
FROM   procedures
WHERE   definition LIKE '%'+@Filter+'%'

END
```

and then run

```
exec [Search] 'text'
```

Comment: The WHERE clause is missing a field reference.  You should also reference the schema (sys)