# How to find list of tables used in stored procedure with “nolock”?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have more than 1000 Stored procedures, due to some dirty programmers they would have used 'nolock' for stored procedure tables.

Now i am facing lots and lots of issues due to this issue in daily basics.

For some reasons i cant remove all the `nolock` key words from SP but i need to know in which stored procedure it occurs.

Example:

Let us consider a store-procedure(`sp_user`) used two tables (`tbl_salary`) and (`tbl_account`) and if one table (`tbl_account`) end with `(NOLOCK)` then i need to return following details.

```
**S.N    SP_Name   Table_name**

1      sp_user  tbl_account
```

Any help will me much appreciated...

Comment: I think you are going to have to search through the source code for the stored procedures.

Comment: You can search for `nolock` keyword in all the sprocs as given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704105/search-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Comment: but to find the table names .. i doubt there is a simple builtin-sln in sql server

Comment: @Deepshikha : Inbuilt options will not help me to return dynamic output.

Answer (score 1):

The below query work as your need you can use directly in your sql server

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS ( 
    SELECT o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row 
    FROM sysdepends d INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id=d.id INNER JOIN sysobjects oo ON oo.id=d.depid WHERE o.xtype = 'P'
) 
SELECT proc_name, table_name 
FROM stored_procedures 
WHERE row = 1 and proc_name in (
        select specific_name 
        from information_schema.routines 
        where routine_definition like  N'%nolock%'
    ) 
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

Comment: It does't work need to get result based on table names. Your query didn't return table names.

Comment: Hey you can chek above query

Answer (score 0):

Try the following simple query. This will give all SP,functions and views in which "NoLock" is using irrespective of which manner.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules m 
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
    ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%nolock%'
```

And following for stored procedures only

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%nolock%' and o.type = 'P'
```

I have worked around it and have a solution. Please try:

```
;WITH stored_procedures AS (
SELECT 
o.name AS proc_name, oo.name AS table_name,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by o.name,oo.name ORDER BY o.name,oo.name) AS row
FROM sysdepends d 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id=d.id
INNER JOIN sys.objects oo ON oo.object_id=d.depid AND oo.type = 'U'
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id=o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules mod ON o.object_id = mod.object_id
WHERE o.type = 'P' AND o.Is_MS_Shipped = 0 
AND m.definition Like '%nolock%')
SELECT proc_name, table_name FROM stored_procedures
WHERE row = 1
ORDER BY proc_name,table_name
```

Comment: And if you want to search only Stored Procedures then, use below query:

SELECT DISTINCT o.name AS Object_Name
FROM sys.sql_modules m 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON m.object_id=o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%nolock%' and o.type = 'P'

Comment: If you edit your answer to include that last comment's information, it will look much better!

Comment: @Ragul - did you find your answer?

Comment: @Dev your answer will not help me to get list of table name, It will show only list of Sp in which 'nolock' keyword used

Comment: Ok. Let me try this. I will update my answer if I got the solution.

Comment: @Ragul - Please see my last updated answer and let me know you are desiring the same one or not.

Comment: Dear Dev: Please note that if a sp contains two tables even one table with nolock then all the table name will come alone with it. we need to split the definition to get the values. Even i tried lot but cant find the answers.

Comment: Then only possible thing you have to search for nolock in SP definitions and find with which tables it is using. Its not possible by a sql query.