# How to Find from where a SP is executed from?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have already checked the dependencies, but I couldn't find where the SP is executed from in SQL Server 2016? Is there any other way to find it?

Comment: If you can't find it in the dependencies, it's not called directly by any other database object. It may be called by client code or dynamic SQL. You could try [searching all stored procedure text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704105/search-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server) for the sap's name

Comment: For client code though, you'd have to capture a trace using eg Extended Events to see who's calling that stored procedure

Comment: Ohh okay..Thank u so much