# Find specific user-defined table type in all stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I must delete and create a user-defined table type. This type is being used in different stored procedures.

Is there a way to find all stored procedures where the type is in use?
So that can I be sure that I find all stored procedures.

I made this attempt:

```
select * 
from sys.table_types 
where name = 'typeLT_LiefertreueLieferant'
```

So I get the `system_type_id`, but I have no way to the components in the stored procedure.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704105/search-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Comment: Ideally you will already have an SSDT representation of your database, so you won't need to search MSSQL itself; but assuming you don't, then one option is to search through `sys.sql_modules.definition` using `LIKE`. Unfortunately (non-memory/compiled, i..e _normal_) stored-procedures don't use `SCHEMABINDING` so have fun....

Comment: Being used how? As a TVP? If so look at `select OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) AS schema_name, OBJECT_NAME(object_id) as object_name from sys.parameter_type_usages where TYPE_NAME(user_type_id) = 'typeLT_LiefertreueLieferant'` - though this won't find usages other than as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below T-SQL might work for you:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION, ROUTINE_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES as ISR
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%typeLT_LiefertreueLieferant%' AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE' 
order by ROUTINE_DEFINITION
```

And If wanted to check for all table type then below T-SQL will help:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION, ROUTINE_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES as ISR
cross join sys.table_types  TY
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%'+ TY.name +'%' AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE' 
order by ROUTINE_DEFINITION
```