How to Replace any instance of item in a SQL Database
I'm working with an MS SQL Database where the object 'Target' is extensively used. It appears in various forms such as a field name (Target), a variable (@Target), and within several table-valued functions.
Traditionally, to replace such an object, I've used SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to generate scripts for the affected database objects, then manually edited these scripts to make the replacements, and finally created a new database using the modified scripts. This method, although effective, can be quite laborious.
I'm seeking a more streamlined approach. Is there a way to directly search for and replace references to the 'Target' object across the entire database without having to first generate and manually edit the scripts? Ideally, I'm looking for a solution that can be implemented directly within the existing database.

There isn't one, when you rename an object you a warned that it can (and will) break existing code in objects like stored procedure. In truth, is renaming the object, when it so widely used across the system really a wise decision?

You could theoretically make a script that searches trough your tables and stored procedures. Then lists the ones that contains the Target. Then replace that Target with NewTarget. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query for a insight into how do this for example with a table. Following links for searching tables and SP's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849652/find-all-tables-containing-column-with-specified-name and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704105/search-text-in-stored-procedure-in-sql-server

Create a view called target that points to the new object. Or even better, a synonym.

What you can do is search for all database "objects" that use this item, an example of such a script is this
SELECT DISTINCT
       o.name AS Object_Name,
       o.type_desc,
       m.*
FROM   sys.sql_modules m
  INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE m.definition Like '%Target%'

then you can correct each proc/function/view or whatever
To check if all has worked out wel, you can try to find invalid objects like this query, but note that this will not always return every problem, but it helped me alot with replace actions like this. For example this query has problems with triggers because it can't find reference for deleted and inserted
select * from
(
select QuoteName(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(referencing_id)) + '.' + QuoteName(OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id)) AS ProblemObject,
       o.type_desc,
       ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
         + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
         + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name) AS MissingReferencedObject
from   sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed
  left join sys.objects o on sed.referencing_id=o.object_id
where  (is_ambiguous = 0)
and  (OBJECT_ID(ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_server_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_database_name) + '.', '')
       + ISNULL(QuoteName(referenced_schema_name) + '.', '')
       + QuoteName(referenced_entity_name)
     ) IS NULL)

) a
--where  a.MissingReferencedObject not in ('[inserted]','[deleted]')
order by ProblemObject, MissingReferencedObject


Hi @GuidoG, thanks for reaching out. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but thanks for getting in touch.
